# setTimeout(function() {doSth();}, 3) vs setTimeout(doSth, 3)?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, anonymous-function

Of the above, which is preferable? Why would you use

```
setTimeout(function() { anotherFunction(); }, 3);
```

instead of

```
setTimeout(anotherFunction, 3);
```

?

For example, [the documentation for the testing tool jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-44) uses an anonymous inner function without parameters. But why? What are the advantages/disadvantages of the anonymous function style?

Comment: Actually because many people dont know about the third following params...

Comment: Generally speaking? Or just for this specific case with `setTimeout`?

Comment: @MinusFour: I meant specifically with `setTimeout`. Are there differences to generally that I missed?

Comment: @Jonasw: did you mean the possibility to pass parameters to the called method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary advantage is the scope where the variables exists.

Take this two scenarios for example:

### Scenario 1

```
function foo() {
  let element = document.getElementById('bar');
  element.classList.add('some-effect');
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.remove('some-effect');
  }, 1000);
}
```

### Scenario 2

```
function foo() {
  let element = document.getElementById('bar');
  element.classList.add('some-effect');
  setTimeout(removeEffect, 1000);
}

function removeEffect() {
  let element = document.getElementById('bar');
  element.classList.remove('some-effect');
}
```

In the first scenario you have access to the `element` because you are inside the scope of the `foo` function.

In the second one you have to search again the element in the `removeEffect` function because the scope has changed.

If you need to reuse variables of the scope where you are working, use the code of the first scenario. If you don't really need the variables in the scope or want to make the function reusable, use the second scenario